# printing values in 2d 10x10 table, in C

Tags: c, arrays

Am trying to print out the values that are prime and not prime onto a 10x10 table. Arrays are confusing and cannot seem to get it, but I am assuming I need an array. The double XX on the expected output are just white space if the value is not prime.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;


    for (i = 2; i <= 101; i++)
    {
        for (j = 2; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if ( i % j == 0)
            {   
                printf(" ");
                break;
            }
         }
         if( i == j)
         {
            printf("%d", i);
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
02 03 XX 05 XX 07 XX XX XX 11  
XX 13 XX XX XX 17 XX 19 XX XX  
XX 23 XX XX XX XX XX 29 XX 31  
XX XX XX XX XX 37 XX XX XX 41  
XX 43 XX XX XX 47 XX XX XX XX  
XX 53 XX XX XX XX XX 59 XX 61  
XX XX XX XX XX 67 XX XX XX 71
XX 73 XX XX XX XX XX 79 XX XX
XX 83 XX XX XX XX XX 89 XX XX
XX XX XX XX XX 97 XX XX XX 101
```

Comment: `my_array` unused. do you want prime-number store to array?

Comment: There is a lot to start with, what are the values in my_array, array in c are 0 indexed, why do you start from 2, and why do you print only half the values of the array in a triangular fashion ? perhaps before writing code you need to think about your algorithms

Comment: It's not clear to me what numbers exactly you want to print. But it might be helpful for you to know that `'\n'` is a new line character (use it like `printf("%d\n", i); /* prints an integer, then starts a new line */`)

Answer (score 3):

What? No, no, no, you don't have to do all this complex stuff.

Just use a double loop:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc57bd52c29a419f

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int my_array[10][10];

    //Fill the array
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            my_array[i][j] = 10*i + j;
        }
    }

    //Print out the array
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", my_array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Make sure you get the indexing right. It should be relatively simple; never access the 10th index of an array of 10 elements; it's 0-9 and make sure that you print out the right value.

Comment: Arrays are just a structure for data, much like (x,y) coordinate for matrices; i.e. an `int arr[10][10]` will have bounds from 0 to 9 and 0 to 9 in C++, including 0, making for a total 10x10 matrix or 2D-vector. **Also, you didn't explain that you wanted prime numbers anywhere in the question, which means you better go back and edit it.**

Answer (score 2):

Divide and conquer:  compute "is it a prime" and "print array" as separate problems.

The key is to break the task into manageable parts - architect the solution - and than implement the pieces.  Use constants like `I_MAX` rather than use a naked magic number like 101.   With the `print_array()`, think of how to print 1 element and wrap that into a loop of 10.  Then wrap that loop into something that stops when all the numbers are printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define I_MIN 2
#define I_MAX 101

// OP all ready has code for IsPrime() - here is an alternative
bool IsPrime(int i, const bool *set) {
  if (i <= 3) {
    return i >= 2;
  }
  int divisor = 2;
  for (;;) {
    if (i % divisor == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    if (i / divisor <= divisor) {
      return true;
    }
    // get next prime
    while (!set[++divisor])
      ;
  }
}

void print_array(const bool *set, int min, int max) {
  int width = 10;
  for (int i = min; i <= max;) {
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
      // Print the number
      if (set[i]) printf("%02d ", i);
      else fputs("XX ", stdout);
      i++;
      if (i > max)
        break;
    }
    fputc('\n', stdout);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  bool set[I_MAX + 1];  

  // Populate the set
  for (int i = 0; i <= I_MAX; i++) {
    set[i] = IsPrime(i, set);
  }

  // display the set
  print_array(set, I_MIN, I_MAX);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just issues with formatting, it looks like you're missing the newline between rows. Before the end of your outer for loop add:

```
if((i -1) % 10 == 0) printf("\n");
```

This condition prints a newline every 10 iterations. The `-1` is needed because  the outer loop is started at 2.